# Facebook share on IOS safari not working with javascript SDK

Tags: ios, facebook-share

I am using facebook share using javascript SDK where i need callback function in angular.js as below.

```
<button type="button" class="btn share-btn fb-share" ng-click="shareOnSocialMediaFB();"> </button>
```

---

Javascript code is as below  (angularJs)

```
$scope.shareOnSocialMediaFB = function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
        $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
        FB.init({
          appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX', //replace with your app ID
          version: 'v2.3'
        });
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            mobile_iframe: true,
            title: 'TEST',
            description: "TEST",
            href: 'www.example.com',
          },
          function(response) {
            //
        });
    });  
};
```

This is working fine with every desktop and browser. But for iphone safari browser FB is not getting open not in popup or in new tab. 
How can i make it working so that on successful share i can do my stuff on callback function?